# What is the highest check frequncy in WebDriverWait (python+selenium)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

I'm using python3+selenium+Chrome, and I wonder what is the highest poll_frequncy here? cuz I really want it to be able to react fast enough...

eg：
`WebDriverWait(driver, 50, 0.05).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mui-amount-increase")))`

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish? Default is 500 miliseconds which is pretty quick. You also don't want your polling time to be less than the code execution time. So really you can set this as low as you want in MS, but I wonder why and what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: @DMart there're these goods in a shopping website. So many people want to buy it and as soon as the goods r available, it sold out really quick. I never succeeded. So im wondering if my code is not fast enough or its just my net speed.

Comment: oh, you might want to do a loop (and possibly threading) rather than using a webdriver wait.